# Reading the emails of all users using Microsoft Graph API by creating an app with Application Level permissions

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an app within the Azure app management portal that will serve as a template to be used with any tenant. Basically what we are trying to do, is create a connector that will be approved using admin consent, and receive application level permissions to read all the emails in the organization using Graph API.

What I have managed to do so far is create an app within our own tenant and get *application level permissions* for this tenant only. This enabled me to successfully read all emails in my organization only (which is not possible using *delegated permissions*).

What is the right way to receive application level permissions for any tenant, using admin consent? Is the only way to do it, for the specific tenant to manually add an application that will receive admin consent?

I am using django with the social_core module.

Something does not add up...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a single application (with a single client ID and set of credentials that you control), configure the permissions you desire/require, and then customers from different tenants can each grant admin consent for your application, in their own tenant.

If your application/service does not have a sign-in experience (i.e. it is *exclusively* used as a background service and users never sign in to it), you can construct the admin consent URL, such as:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent
   ?client_id={client_id}&scope=.default&redirect_uri={your_redirect_url}
```

You can read more about the admin consent endpoint at: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent